# Organisation of Python code. One big file versus multiple modules, packages

Tags: python

My python project is organised as one big file right now. The code is organised with def functions and I have a good overview. I like that because it enables me to work in one file only and i can look for code snippets that i have already done easily via the search function.

However, I keep reading and people keep telling me that an organisation of python code in modules and importing them is best practice.

Can you please point out why organising python code in modules is better than having one large script.

Comment: come back to your one big file 6 months later. You'll know your answer. tl;dr though, it really depends on actually how many things you're dealing with, how big the file is, and whether you can make logical subgroupings in the code.

Comment: I definetly have those groupings. and if I would rearrange my code, I would organise my modules in the exact same way as I do with my functions right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mainly a matter of preference while planning maintainability. Some people can manage 10 thousand lines of codes in a single file without even flinching. However, when you are putting so much in a single file, problems like separating **namespaces**, naming **variables**, **functions** and even **classes** start to occur.

Introducing **Module-level** separation is a good practice when your application/library starts to get bigger. But when even module-level separation is not enough, you know it's time to create **packages**.

Answer (score 1):

When you structure your code in Python, it's useful  to think in terms of namespaces (mapping from names to objects) : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html .

Then you can organize your code (depending on his complexity) in modules (file containing Python definitions and statements) and then packages ( a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”): https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html